# Xcode: CollectionViewCell image becomes visible when tapped, where it shouldn't

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am setting collectionView for a game. In each cell there is a bomb image, star image or it is empty. At the beginning of game all the cells are closed and images are not seen but only a green background. 
when any cell in the first row is tapped it opens and shows the related image with a pink background, green background disappears as expected. After a cell is open in the first row when any cell in other rows is tapped, the new cell shouldn't open.
The problem is: this newly tapped cell in other rows opens and shows the same image which was open in the first row. In the first opened cell if there is a bomb or star image the problem occurs, however if the cell is empty (which shows only pink background after opening) then I don't see this problem.

I'm using Xcode-10.3 and swift-5. I tried different iPhone models in Xcode's virtual device set and problem continues. I have cleaned program (shift+command+K) and problem continues. 
When I tap rows other than first row at the beginning they are not open as expected.
When the unexpected cell opens then I tap again and it disappears.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    openCellTapped(at: indexPath)
  }
```

```
     // open the cell in a given in an indexPath
  private func openCellTapped(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Find the cell in the given indexPath
    let cell = collectionViewGame.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    // Find the item in the given indexPath
    let item = gameManager.getCellDataAt(indexPath: indexPath)

    // find the tapped cell's row number (first row is the lowest, however first
    // indexpath.section is most upper)
    let tappedCellRowNumber = numOfRows - indexPath.section - 1
    // if the tapped cell is already open return
    guard item.getItemCurrentOpenState() == false else { return }

    // At the beginning of game only cells in first row can be opened
    // if the tappedCell is in the first row
    if tappedCellRowNumber == 0 {
      // check all the cells in the first row. If all the cells are closed then
      // open any tapped cell
      for col in 0...numOfCols - 1 {
        let tempIndexPath = IndexPath(item: col, section: indexPath.section)
        let tempItem = gameManager.getCellDataAt(indexPath: tempIndexPath)
        guard tempItem.getItemCurrentOpenState() == false else { return }
        if col == numOfCols - 1 { item.openItem() }
      }

      // if in the first row there are some open cells, check if any neighbour of tapped cell is open
      // if any neighbour is open then open the item
      // if any neighbour is not open then dont open

      // if the tapped cell is not in the first row
    } else {
      // check if any neighbour of tapped cell is open
      // if there is at least one open neighbour then open the cell
      // if no neighbour is open then dont open the item.
    }

    // update items in the cell
    cell.updateItemInCell(item: item)
    // Reload items in collectionView after pressing
    collectionViewGame.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
  }
```

```
  enum itemState { case Bomb, Star, Empty }
  var itemCurrentState: itemState = .Empty

  var isItemOpen = false

  func getItemCurrentOpenState() -> Bool {
    return isItemOpen
  }

  func openItem() {
    isItemOpen = true
  }

  func getItemCurrentState() -> itemState {
    return itemCurrentState
  }
```

```
    func updateItemInCell(item: ItemInCell) {
    let itemState = item.getItemCurrentState()
    // set the background color of cell according to item's open state
    // if item is open
    if item.getItemCurrentOpenState() {
      // pink
      imageViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.2, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.6)

      // For each state of item define the image
      switch itemState {
      case .Bomb:
        imageViewCell.image = UIImage(named: "bomb.png")
      case .Star:
        imageViewCell.image = UIImage(named: "rewarding_star")
      case .Empty:
        break
      }
      // if item is closed
    } else {
      // green
      imageViewCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.5, blue: 0.35, alpha: 0.6)
    }
```

Program doesn't give any error messages. In order the cell to open getItemCurrentOpenState() value should be true. I checked and even its value is false again the cell opens.

Comment: Cells are reused and you don't set the image to `nil` in the `else` case of `updateItemInCell`  nor in the `.empty`  state of your case statement (BTW enumeration values should start with a lower case letter)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paulw11 . I did exactly what you said. And now it works perfectly.